# How can I get rid of spacing in Java BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I programmed following `ListPanel`:
[image: ListPanel good]

with Javas `BoxLayout`:

```
public class ListPanel extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<EntryHolder> entries;

public ListPanel(){
    entries = new ArrayList<>();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    updatePanel();
}

public void updatePanel() {
    removeAll();

    synchronized (entries) {
        for (EntryHolder entryHolder : entries) {
            EntryPanel entryPanel = new EntryPanel(entryHolder);
            entryPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width, 50));
            add(entryPanel);
        }
    }
}

public void addEntry(EntryHolder entryHolder) {
    synchronized (entries) {
        entries.add(entryHolder);
    }
}

public void clearEntries() {
    synchronized (entries) {
        entries.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ListPanel` is part of a `JScrollPane` which allows scrolling. An `EntryPanel` is a `JPanel` which consists of two other `JPanels`: one is always visible and the other one is only visible when the first one was clicked. The hidden one is `setVisible(false)` before I run the `add()` function on it. The EntryPanel uses a BorderLayout:

```
add(shownEntryPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(hiddenEntryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This approach works great for my scrollable list when there are enough entries to fill the whole `ListPanel` but as soon as there are fewer entries, white spacing occurs between `EntryPanels`:

[image: ListPanel bad]

I tried a lot of different layouts but I couldn't find one that does exactly what I want: position the panels from top to bottom without spaces but still having the ability to freely expand entries. I know that [MigLayout](http://miglayout.com/) is an option but I would like to NOT use any additional libraries.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: The layout that is most complex but allows you to do what you are aiming at is GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extra space is available in the panel, the BoxLayout will attempt to allocate that space to each component in the panel up to the maximum size of the component.

The maximum size of a panel is Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Override the `getMaximumSize()` method of your EntryPanel.

Something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize()
{
    Dimension preferred = getPreferredSize();
    Dimension maximum = new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, preferred.getHeight());
 
    return maximum;
}
```

This will prevent extra space being allocated to the EntryPanel, so there will be no gap.

Another solution is to use a "wrapper" panel:

```
JPanel boxLayoutPanel = new JPanel(...)
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(boxLayoutPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
parentPanel.add(wrapper);
```

The `PAGE_START` area of the `BorderLayout` respects the height of components, so all components are displayed at their preferred heights and no gaps will appear between components.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to add a *glue* to the panel. In this case as the last component. A *glue* is described in Oracle docu as:

> Glue - Use this to specify where excess space in a layout should go. Think of it as a kind of elastic glue — stretchy and expandable, yet taking up no space unless you pull apart the components that it is sticking to. For example, by putting horizontal glue between two components in a left-to-right box, you make any extra space go between those components, instead of to the right of all the components.

Comment: Extra space is allocated to each component up to the maximum size of the component. This solution works for components like a JButton where the maximum size is the same as the preferred size. It won't work for a panel since its maximum size is Integer.MAX_VALUE.